# Tricky SQL including outer join and case

Tags: sql-server-2008, case, outer-join

I use data from http://geonames.org. The table structure is as follows:

```
GN_Name 1 - 0:N GN_AlternateName
```

They are linked on:

```
(PK)GN_Name.GeoNameId == (FK)GN_AlternateName.GeoNameId
```

GN_Name is the main table containing all place names.
GN_AlternateName contains names in other languages if any.

**EX:**

```
GN_Name.Name                   - Stockholm

GN_AlternateName.AlternateName - Estocolmo (if IsoLanguage=="es")
```

**Rules:**

- I want to use GN_AlternateName.AlternateName if it exists for the specified language and if it starts with the search string.
- If not, i want to use GN_Name.Name if it starts with the search string.
- I want GeoNameId to be unique.

Basically I could outer join in first record only, but that seemed to decrease performance.

I've got the following SQL (basically modified SQL from a LINQ query). The problem is that it only finds 'Estocolmo' if search string starts with "stock". "estoc" yields nothing.

```
select 
distinct(n.GeoNameId) as Id,
an.IsoLanguage,
CASE WHEN (an.AlternateName like N'estoc%') 
    THEN an.AlternateName
    ELSE n.Name 
END AS [The name we are going to use]
from GN_Name as n
LEFT OUTER JOIN GN_AlternateName as an
ON n.GeoNameId = an.GeoNameId
AND 'es' = an.IsoLanguage
WHERE n.Name like N'estoc%'
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks Rahul and Lee D.

I now have the following:

```
select 
distinct(n.GeoNameId) as Id,
an.IsoLanguage,
CASE WHEN (an.AlternateName like N'estoc%') 
    THEN an.AlternateName
    ELSE n.Name 
END AS [The final name]
from GN_Name as n
LEFT OUTER JOIN GN_AlternateName as an
ON n.GeoNameId = an.GeoNameId
AND 'es' = an.IsoLanguage
WHERE (n.Name LIKE N'estoc%' OR an.AlternateName LIKE N'estoc%')
```

This performs LIKE twice on an.AlternateName. Is there any way i could get rid of on LIKE clause?

**UPDATE 2**
Andriy M made a nice alternative query using COALESCE. I changed it a little bit and ended up with the following:

```
SELECT Id, LocalisedName
FROM (
  SELECT
    n.GeoNameId AS Id,
    an.IsoLanguage,
    COALESCE(an.AlternateName, n.Name) AS LocalisedName
  FROM n
    LEFT JOIN GN_AlternateName AS an ON n.GeoNameId = an.GeoNameId
    AND IsoLanguage = 'es'
) x
WHERE LocalisedName LIKE 'estoc%'
```

This query does exactly what i am looking for. Thanks!

Comment: First of all, you seem to mistakenly believe that `DISTINCT` is only applied to `n.GeoNameId`, while it is not so. `DISTINCT` applies to all the columns and expressions being retrieved.

Comment: Also, what happens if the localised the name you are searching for doesn't exist? That is, the outcome is actually predictable: you'll get no rows. But is that acceptable?

Comment: @ Andriy M
You're right. I do wan't the standard name when localized name doesn't exist. However, i only want one record per location. Is there a good way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a probable solution of the problem, which uses a slightly different apporach:

```
SELECT Id, LocalisedName
FROM (
  SELECT
    n.GeoNameId AS Id,
    an.IsoLanguage,
    COALESCE(an.AlternateName, n.Name) AS LocalisedName
  FROM GN_Name AS n
    LEFT JOIN GN_AlternateName AS an ON n.GeoNameId = an.GeoNameId
      AND IsoLanguage = 'es'
) x
WHERE LocalisedName LIKE 'estoc%'
```

(Changed it based on your update.)

Comment: COALESCE. Nice. I'm learning something new everyday. I changed the query a bit to make it return rows where localized name is not available. Having WHERE IsoLanguage = 'es' as a condition at the end presupposes a joined GN_AlternateName. I have updated the question with the final query.

Comment: If you agree on my previous point, please update your query and i will give you the cred. If i'm wrong, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Your select would return 'Estocolmo' when searching for 'Stockholm', which is not the desired result.

I wan't the localized name to have precedence over the standard name when searching. It should return suggestions according to the characters the user typed, not some sort of translation.

Comment: Hm, so searching by 'stock%' instead of 'estoc%' is not an option, because the user input is supposed to be passed to the query as is. All right. But what should be returned if there's no suggestions matching the user input, which is 'estoc%'?

Comment: If there is no match in either GN_Name.Name or GN_AlternateName.AlternateName, nothing should be returned.

Comment: In that case my update is really irrelevant. I've removed it and updated the original solution according to your requirement. Thanks for bearing with me! :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, in your example the value 'Estocolmo' is in the GN_AlternateName.AlternateName column, so would be filtered out by the where clause which only looks at GN_Name.Name. What if you change the last line of SQL to:

```
WHERE n.Name LIKE N'estoc%' OR an.AlternateName LIKE N'estoc%'
```

I'm assuming 'estoc%' is your search string.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to modify the WHERE clause to check in `GN_AlternateName` table as well

```
WHERE n.Name like N'estoc%' OR an.AlternateName like 'N'estoc%'
```